# Setting FontSize for SwipeItem

Tags: maui

Is there a way to change the FontSize of a SwipeItem under iOS in .NET  MAUI?

Right now, do not see this available.

Tried setting it in a resource also but did not work

== Added Screenshot after Designing SwipeItem like propsed and after closing SwipeItem ==

Downside after Closing the self-defined SwipeItem. I could also set the Height correspondingly, but the Heights are normally displayed like that compared to what I saw before changing the SwipeItem and designing on my own:

```xml
<SwipeItems>
    <SwipeItemView>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*, *" WidthRequest="150" ColumnSpacing="0">
            
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate ItemsOverview_SwipeItemEditItem}" BackgroundColor="LightGrey" Style="{StaticResource SwipeItemStyle}">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ItemsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=EditItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate ItemsOverview_SwipeItemDeleteItem}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" TextColor="White" Style="{StaticResource SwipeItemStyle}">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ItemsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=DeleteItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            
        </Grid>
    </SwipeItemView>
</SwipeItems>
```

[image]

**Update**

```cs
public class CustomSwipeView : SwipeView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty OpenFlagProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OpenFlag), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomSwipeView), true, propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(BindableObject sender, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        SwipeView swipeView = sender as SwipeView;
        var openSwipeViewFlag = (bool)newValue;
        
        if (swipeView != null)
        {
            if (openSwipeViewFlag == true)
            {
                swipeView.Close();

                // After closing the initial Value of this
                // flag has to be set to false so that afterwards
                // OpenFlag is set to the initial state 'false'
                ((CustomSwipeView)sender).OpenFlag = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool OpenFlag
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(OpenFlagProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OpenFlagProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
private bool _openFlag;
public bool OpenFlag
{
    get
    {
        return _openFlag;
    }

    set
    {
        _openFlag = value;

        // Leads to my CustomSwipeView OnProperty-Changed
        // only if we really have a change e.g. from false -> true
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OpenFlag));
    }
}

[RelayCommand]
private async Task EditItem(Item item)
{
    OpenFlag = true;

    ...
}
```

**XAML**

```xml
<!-- Just the Background Image and the LinearGradient-->
<Grid Padding="0, 0, 0, -25">

   <views:BackgroundImageView x:Name="BackgroundImage" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

   <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

       <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *">
           
           <!-- Search... -->
           <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate ItemsOverview_SearchItemPlaceholder}"/>

           <!-- CollectionView: Margin to get the ScrollBar to the right and closer to the Border -->
           <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedItems, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CollectionViewStyle}" x:Name="MyCollectionView">

               <!-- Group Header: to group items -->
               <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupedItemList">
                       <VerticalStackLayout>
                           <Label Text="{Binding GroupName, StringFormat=' {0}'}" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}" />
                           <BoxView Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderUnderlineStyle}"/>
                       </VerticalStackLayout>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

               <!-- Group Items -->
               <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type databaseModels:Item}">

                       <!--<controls:CustomSwipeView x:Name="MySwipeView" OpenFlag="{Binding OpenFlag, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:ItemsOverviewView}}, Mode=TwoWay}">-->
                       <controls:CustomSwipeView x:Name="MySwipeView" OpenFlag="{Binding OpenFlag, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ItemsOverviewViewModel}}, Mode=TwoWay}">

                           <!-- Item Name including rectangle with round corners -->
                           <Grid Padding="0, 5">
                               <Frame>
                                   <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                               </Frame>
                           </Grid>

                           <SwipeView.RightItems>
                               
                               <SwipeItems>
                                   <SwipeItemView>
                                       <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*, *" WidthRequest="160" ColumnSpacing="0">
                                           
                                           <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{loc:Translate ItemsOverview_SwipeItemEditItem}" BackgroundColor="LightGrey" Style="{StaticResource SwipeItemStyle}">
                                               <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ItemsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=EditItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                               </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                           </Label>

                                           <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{loc:Translate ItemsOverview_SwipeItemDeleteItem}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkOrange1}" TextColor="White" Style="{StaticResource SwipeItemStyle}">
                                               <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                                   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ItemsOverviewViewModel}}, Path=DeleteItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                               </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                           </Label>
                                           
                                       </Grid>
                                   </SwipeItemView>
                               </SwipeItems>
                               
                               
                           </SwipeView.RightItems>
                       </controls:CustomSwipeView>

                   </DataTemplate>
               </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
           </CollectionView>
       </Grid>

   </Border>

</Grid>
```

Comment: The OpenFlag should be a property in model Item class. And in your EditItem command, you should set the corresponding OpenFlag to true.

Comment: Never mind. I will post some relevant code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [Custom your own swipe items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/swipeview#custom-swipe-items) as an alternative. In the following code, you could define the font size or font attribute as you want for label.

```
<SwipeView>
    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <SwipeItems>
            <SwipeItemView >
                <Grid Margin="10" BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                    WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="50">

                    <Label Text="Check" VerticalOptions="Center"
                            FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </SwipeItemView>
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.LeftItems>
```

**Update**

[image]

You could make some changes.

1.This is for Item model class:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool openFlag;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool OpenFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return openFlag;

        }
        set
        {
            openFlag = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(OpenFlag)));
        }
    }
}
```

2.When you click edit button, you could find the Item you click and set the corresponding OpenFlag to true.

```
public Command EditItemCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command((e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("123");
            var a = e as Item;

            MyText = a.Name + "  edited";
            foreach(Item item in Items)
            {


                if (a == item)
                {
                    item.OpenFlag = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

3.When returning back, you could use Messenger to notify the Item to set the OpenFlag to false,

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewPage1>(this, "Hi", (s) =>
    {
        foreach(Item item in Items)
        {
            if(item.OpenFlag)
            {
                item.OpenFlag = false;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah okay, I see - then have to design it completely on my own :)
Just to learn about that, is this the only option to change it?

Comment: I think you may want to find a property to directly modify the font size for  SwipeItem. But I haven't been able to find one. And if you look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers#views), the ios native control for SwipeView is UIView, which seems no direct api to change font size.

Comment: I added the Code and Screenshot of the own implementation. But, unfortunately, the SwipeItem does show my own Labels in the Background when SwipeItem is closed after clicking one of my Buttons

Comment: I just made a demo based on your code but it work well. See my update gif. Is this effect what you want? Or you could share more code to help us reproduce this issue.

Comment: I am not quite sure if it is the same. Let's take the standard SwipeItem-Behaviour before my change. When I clicked the edit Button a new View was loaded with an OK/Cancel-Button. When I clicked the OK or Cancel-Button the VIew disappeared and when I saw my SwipeItem then, it was closed completely as before it was opened. Now, with my change, when I open and close the SwipeItem by pulling it back to the left it is closed completely as it should. But, when It was opened and I click the Edit-Button my View appears and when I click the OK/Cancel-Button the SwipeItem is as you can see in my image.

Comment: When clicking the edit button in swipeitem, a new popup show? After you dismiss the popup, then it shows the image you add?

Comment: Yes, not a popup, but a new View where the Edit-Details of the current item can be entered. Then closing this view and yes you have the image I showed

Comment: Okay, let me try reproducing it.

Comment: New gif updated. Is this the effect you want?

Comment: This is not what I want. The SwipeItem should be closed and look e.g. like „item 4“ after „click to back“ was clicked. I am currently thinking of sending a Message to the Code-Behind file, use a name for the SwipeItem and use its „Close()“-Method to close it? When „Edit“ or the Views‘ „OK“/„Cancel“-Button was clicked, I am in a ViewModel-Code. So, maybe use an Event to notify the Code-Behind to notify about the trigger for a Close of the SwipeItem

Comment: Yeah, we could [Open and close a SwipeView programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/swipeview#open-and-close-a-swipeview-programmatically). Use Messaging is a good way i think. And I used to follow a similar thread : [How can I initially show the Swipeview programmatically using Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76554459/how-can-i-initially-show-the-swipeview-programmatically-using-listview/76659194#76659194).

Comment: My Problem here is, that I do not have the possibility to access my SwipeItemView via x:Name="MySwipeView" as it is part of a DataTemplate in a CollectionView. I alsow tried the Unfocused-Event of the SwipeItemView, but it is not reached when I see my own SwipeItem closing after the Displayed View has disappeared. Also as Part of the CommandParameter for my EditCommand I have some trouble as it needs to have the current Element that needs to be edited as the CommandParameter - so, providing the SwipeItem would not help here. Any other ideas what I could try?

Comment: Currently, I am also asking myself if this is actually a Bug of the SwipeItem, since when it was closed like shown in my picture and I just click on the closed SwipeItem, it hides the two Labels that are in the Background, automatically.

Comment: Yes. we could not access the swipeitem with x:Name in datatemplate. One of the workaround is using Binding. You could create a custom swipeview and create a Bindableproperty for it, just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76659194/20118901). Also see my new gif updates.

Comment: I updated my code in my initial question with what is implemented right now. The **OpenFlag** in my **CustomSwipeView**-Class is never hit, neither setter nor getter. Is there a way to get around this? I know the OpenFlagProperty needs it. But, acutally the real OpenFlag-Property is implemented in my **ViewModel**. Also after ```swipeView.Close();``` was called, I have to reset my OpenFlag-Property to ```true``` again. If not my OnPropertyChange(OpenFlag) does not notify my CustomSwipeView and call OnPropertyChange in there. Can I make some improvements to get around this?

Comment: Code updated. Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks for the Update - actually so far I haven't used the Item model class :)

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using ```x:DataType="{x:Type databaseModels:Item}"``` .

Comment: I am sorry, this is a different Item and just has the same name you used - this is actually my Item-Class with the data that is displayed

Comment: Never mind. If you set the OpenFlag in viewModel, that means when you click the editItem button, you change all Items' OpenFlag to true. Seems it could also work fine.

Comment: I actually set it to true directly after doing the Close - this will "reset" my Flag